# Mensaje InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember annotations en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, annotation

Al integrar la librería `com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads` a la hora de hacer `build` recibo el error

> InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember
>   annotations. Such InnerClass annotations are ignored.

Uso Android Studio 3.1.3

y dejo el app.gradle de la aplicación:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pruebas.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.kingja.loadsir:loadsir:1.3.6'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.hanihashemi:SlidingPaneLayout:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.marcoscgdev:DialogSheet:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:7.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando por [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517898/android-studio-warning-innerclass-annotations-are-missing-corresponding-enclos) he probado lo siguiente y de momento no sale el error

Añadir en proguard

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep @**annotation** class * {*;}
```